# show this equation of integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

let Ω⊆ℂ be open, f: Ω-> ℂ holomorphic, f 'continuous and γ a piecewise continuously differentiable curve in Ω, foγ is a piecewise continuously differentiable curve and g is continous with: im (foγ) -> ℂ
show

$$\int_{foγ} g(w)\mathrm dw= \int_{γ} g(f(z))f'(z)\mathrm dz$$

i really dont know how to start. ive been trying since hours. what do i have to use to begin? i thought about definition of imγ but it doesnt say something important. can please someone give me a hint?

Comment: You could take some time to start with the definition of complex integrals.

Comment: the second integral is the definition of curve integrals, if f were the curve and g were the function. i saw that already. but what now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a parametrization of $\gamma$ and denote it as $\gamma(t)$, $t\in[a,b]$. Then $f\circ\gamma(t)$ is a parametrization of the curve $f\circ\gamma$. Now what you want to show is:
$$
\int_a^b g(f\circ\gamma(t))\frac{d}{dt}f\circ\gamma(t)\;dt=\int_a^b g(f(\gamma(t)))f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\;dt
$$
This is immediate from the chain rule.

Comment: and where do i have to use the chain rule?

Comment: i cant imagine how on the left side foγ gets to an term without foγ on the right side. its not that clear for me

Comment: @thombirdy: $f\circ\gamma(t)=f(\gamma(t))$ by definition and you calculate $\frac{d}{dt}(f(\gamma(t)))$ by the chain rule. Clear?

Comment: ok to be really sure: the first sentences of you is what i explain first and then i put in the definition like you said in the left term right? and yes i got it, i got that the equation is true. is that all i have to do?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And by definition of the complex integrals, the RHS of mine is equal to that of yours.

Comment: thank you very much. you helped me so much :) !!

Comment: @thombirdy: you are welcome!